# Is there a way to split a multipage .TIFF file into multiple PNG/JPG files using the sharp node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, tiff, sharp

I have a single .tiff file with multiple pages, and would like to split the file into multiple .png or .jpg files (one page becomes one png/jpg image). Due to the nature of my codebase, I would prefer not to use ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick (I am unable to install CLI tools).

I was wondering if there is anyway to go about doing this? I know that sharp can retrieve metadata from the .tiff file that shows me the number of pages within the file. Would something along the lines of the following work:

```
const tiffImage = sharp(tiffFileName).raw().toBuffer();
const metadata = await tiffImage.metadata().then(function(metadata) {
  pages: metadata.pages,
  pageHeight: metadata.pageHeight
});
for (let i = 0; i < metadata.pages; i++) {
  // split tiff file using the pageHeight? lets call this bufferOfOnePage
  sharp(bufferOfOnePage).png().toFile(PNG_OUTPUT_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass `page` in the options of [sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-constructor).

> options.page number  page number to start extracting from for multi-page input (GIF, WebP, AVIF, TIFF, PDF), zero based. (optional, default 0)

```js
    sharp(bufferOfOnePage, {page: i}).png().toFile(PNG_OUTPUT_NAME);
```